# inserting a form on page using JavaScript bookmark

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to make a bookmark that inserts a form onto the page. However ,when the bookmark button is clicked the entire page is white except for the form, instead of the form being on or embedded within the page itself.

Here is what I have

```
javascript:document.write('<textarea name="text" rows="4" cols="49">text</textarea>');
```

Comment: That's what document.write does. Don't use it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write. DOM manipulation with Javascript is well documented https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement try searching around first

Answer (score 0):

```
    javascript:(()=>{
          var html    = `
          
    <form>
        <textarea name="text" rows="4" cols="49">text</textarea>
        <input type='submit' />
    </form>
    
          `;
          
          var root   = document.createElement('div');
          root.id   = 'bookmark-root';
          addstyle(root,{
                position:'fixed',
                top:0,
                left:0,
                width:'435px',
                zIndex:999999,
                background:'lightgray',
                border:'1px solid orange',
                padding:'10px'
          });
          addmouse();
          
          document.body.appendChild(root);
          
          var div   = document.createElement('div');
          addstyle(div,{position:'relative',marginTop:'30px'});      
          div.innerHTML=html;
          root.appendChild(div);
          
          var close=document.createElement('input');
          close.type='button';
          close.value='close';
          addstyle(close,{
                position:'absolute',
                left:0,
                top:0
          });
          close.onclick=e=>root.parentNode.removeChild(root);
          root.appendChild(close);
          
          
          console.log('added');
    
          function addstyle(node,style){
                for(var key in style)node.style[key]=style[key];
          }
          
          function addmouse(){
          
                root.onmousedown=md;
                document.documentElement.onmouseup=mu;
                
                var ox,oy;
                function md(e){
                      ox=e.pageX;oy=e.pageY;
                      document.documentElement.onmousemove=mm;
                }
                function mm(e){
                      var x=e.pageX-ox,y=e.pageY-oy;
                      var left    = (parseInt(root.style.left)+x)+'px';
                      var top     = (parseInt(root.style.top)+y)+'px';
                      addstyle(root,{left,top});
                      ox=e.pageX;oy=e.pageY;
                }
                function mu(){
                      document.documentElement.onmousemove=null;
                }
                
          }
          
    })()
```

edit: now you can move it around by clicking and dragging